Differences in the calculation logic of grouping_id in HIVE
I have recently encountered an issue while using Hive 2.3.9 version.
When my group by is set to "a, b, c" and the grouping_sets is set to (a, b, (a, b)).
In last Hive version， the grouping__id result is when "a" then 1 when "b" then 2 when "a,b" then 3. But in the 2.3.9 version, I found the result is when "a" then 1 when "b" then 2 when "a, b" then 0. The new regular look like same as Spark grouping__id Regular.
I remember the Hive Grouping__id regular is from low to high, the defualt all is 0, when the dimension appear then reset to 1, finally to tranfer decimalism.
But now it looks like been channged.
So did Hive make some changes ???
